# what does the create command wrong, ErrorORA-00903: invalid table name and the FK reference to pk is correct?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
    SQL> create table Orders(
  2  order_ID number(5) primary key,
  3  order_Date date,
  4  customer_ID number(3),
  5  Distributor_ID varchar2(8),
  6  Distributor_Fee varchar2(6),
  7  total_Due varchar2(7),
  8  foreign key(customer_ID) references customer(customer_ID));

Table created.
SQL> insert into orders
  2  (order_ID, order_Date, customer_ID, Distributor_ID, Distributor_Fee, total_Due)
  3  values (34561, '07/04/2008', 23, 'DEN8001', '$22.00', '$145.74');
values (34561, '07/04/2008', 23, 'DEN8001', '$22.00', '$145.74')
               *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: your question does not contain the error message you mention in your title.

Comment: the error message is ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01843: not a valid month, i put it on the title

Comment: Your title has ORA-00903. Not sure why, you don't seem to be experiencing that.

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month i think it is this one

Comment: `'07/04/2008'` is a string, not a date. You should explicitly convert the string to a date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this (I cut out all but date fields to pinpoint the issue)

```
insert into orders (..., order_Date, . . . )
values (. . . , TO_DATE('07/04/2008', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), . . . .);
```

Basically, you need to convert `varchar2` to `date` using "Format Model". I don't know your locality so you might need to switch `MM/DD/YYYY` with `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Other issues that you might have in the future  - saving numeric data as string... Think that one day you might need run the totals or something like that.